# Dynamically assign the dataType of a Set

Tags: apex

I need to dynamically assign a datatype to a Set.

`Set<dataType> elemensSet = new Set<dataType>();`

Is this possible?

Comment: You might explain why you think this functionality is necessary. Without knowing your high level goals, it is difficult to suggest workarounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible...to an extent (I do this myself in the trigger framework that I developed).

Apex doesn't really have a robust system for reflection/introspection, but there is [the 'Type' class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm). Specifically, the `Type.forName()` and `Type.newInstance()` methods.

`forName()` (a static class method) allows you to pass in a type name (SObject type names, Apex class names, Apex interface names, etc...) as a string, and get a `Type` instance as a result.

`newInstance()` (an instance method of the `Type` class) allows you to, well, create a new instance of that type. This method returns a generic `Object`, and thus really needs to be explicitly type-cast to be of any use.

It's that required type-casting that makes this solution not as useful/powerful as it could be. As-is, this feature is mostly suited to making object factories that cast a child (apex) class as an instance of its parent class, or to cast a class as an instance of an interface.

That said, there is a small amount of trickery that we can pull off with collections.

```
List<SObject> sobjList;
Account testAcc = new Account(Name = 'My Test Account');
String listType = 'Account';

// Part of the 'trick' that we can do is determine the exact type of List that we want
//   at runtime.
// In my own trigger framework, I use something similar to abstract out trigger context
//   variables (to make isolating the testing of various framework components
//   from actually running triggers/performing dml possible)
sobjList = (List<SObject>)Type.forName('List<' + listType + '>').newInstance();
sobjList.add(testAcc);

// The point of this code is to show that we can down-cast from a generic type
//   to a concrete type.
// This is the other part of the 'trick'
List<Account> testImplicitDownCastList = sobjList;
Account otherTestAcc = (Account)sobjList[0];
otherTestAcc = testDownCastList[0];

system.debug('generic list: ' + sobjList);
system.debug('down-cast: ' + testDownCastList);
```

It should be noted that implicit down-casting (the most useful type) like I do in my example only applies to `Lists` (not `Map`, nor `Set`), and will break as soon as you would add something that isn't an `Account` to `sobjList`.

The reasons behind that are complex, and are explored a bit more in depth in one of the questions that I myself have asked: [Is there a specific reason why we can't upcast Sets?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-we-cant-upcast-sets)

Answer (score 6):

Reflection is very limited in apex. It is partially implemented via [Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) class.

you can do something like

```
Type t = Type.forName('Set<String>');
Set<String> values = (Set<String>)t.newInstance();
values.add('foo');
```

Comment: It is not dynamic yet. I guess that is the better it gets. Salesforce has to implement generics.