# Map values not recognized as an SObject list for DML

Tags: map, casting

One of my fellow developers was working on a class that converted feedback from a REST callout into SObjects. Part of the class was storing the feedback in a map, and then attempted to upsert the map values. The code looked similar to the snippet below:

```
Map<Id, Feedback__c> feedbackMap = new Map<Id, Feedback__c>();

// Fill map and perform other functions....

List<Feedback__c> updatedFeedback = (List<Feedback__c>) feedbackMap.values();
upsert updatedFeedback;
```

The upsert resulted in the below error:

> System.TypeException: DML on generic List only allowed for
>   insert, update or delete

I'd remembered getting this before when attempting to perform DML on something that wasn't an SObject or `List<SObject>`, like `Set<SObject>`, so I recommended he try adding the map values to a list instead of just casting the map values:

```
List<Feedback__c> updatedFeedback = new List<Feedback__c>();
updatedFeedback.addAll(feedbackMap.values());
upsert updatedFeedback;
```

This worked no problem. I'm glad that my solution worked, but I want to know exactly why it worked. Was there something that was causing the cast map values to still be typed as `List<Object>`? Why did adding the values work instead of casting?

Comment: Are you sure that the map being used in the code that was failing was declared with a concrete SObject type instead of being a `Map<Id, SObject>`?

Comment: So it was declared as `Map<Id, SObject>`. Map.values() should still return as least as List<SObject>, which should upsert fine, right? And why did explicitly casting it as a list of a concrete SObject not work as we expected?

Comment: The error you got rules out upsert on `List<SObject>`, but I'm not sure why casting to a collection of a concrete SObject type first didn't work. I may play around with that a bit tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I coudn't replicate the issue from provided example. If you could elaborate I may be able to give you more precise answer, why `addAll()` worked for you.

---

The key here is that the declarion has been with `Map<Id, SObject>`. And `upsert` does not work on SObject collections (there is a ways arround it).

I was able to reproduce the same behaviour with following code. (I belive you could have something similar at the beginning)

```
String response = '[{"attributes": {"type": "Account"}, "id": "00100000000000001", "name":"Test"}]';
List<SObject> objs = (List<SObject>)JSON.deserialize(response, List<SObject>.class);

Map<Id, SObject> sObjectMap = new Map<Id, SObject>(objs);
List<Account> acountList = (List<Account>) sObjectMap.values();

upsert acountList;
// Runtime exception: System.TypeException: DML on generic List<SObject> only allowed for insert, update or delete
```

---

Simplified example, everyone can try:

```
List<Account> accounts = (List<Account>) new List<SObject>{
    new Account(Name = 'Doe'),
    new Account(Name = 'Jackson')
};
```

- I've created collection variable of type List that should hold Account objects.
- I've actually initialized it as `List<SObject>`.
- But my `List<SObject>` holds Account instances only.
- Apex will let me deploy (and build) the class.
- Remember `accountList` variable actually points to `List<SObject>`.

So far so good, you could be doing `insert`, `update` and `delete` DML statements on `accountList`.

And if I try upsert

```
upsert accountList;
// Runtime exception: System.TypeException: DML on generic List<SObject> only allowed for insert, update or delete
```

Why? Becuase casting List collections actually does nothing. Runtime initialized `accountList` as `List<SObject>` and does not care that variable pointing to the object says it should be `List<Account>`.

---

Now I will try to explain the confusion behind this.

- Casting isn't magic, you are only telling the **compiler** that Object A is more of a type Object B ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289493/766837)).
- Apex is based on JVM. In Java you can't cast collections (without generics you can't and we don't have generics in Apex).
- Not related: *In Java you can cast arrays. I don't how Apex List is implemented, but I believe it's rather the ArrayList than simple old Array*
- What is very confusing is that Apex compiler will let you cast List collections but no Map and Set.

---

```
List<Account> accounts = (List<Account>) new List<SObject>();
// Will compile, no runtime exceptions
```

```
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = (Map<Id, Account>) new Map<Id, SObject>();
// Will compile, but runtime exception:
// FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map to Map
```

```
Set<Account> accountSet = (Set<Account>) new Set<SObject>();
// Won't compile with message:
// Incompatible types since an instance of Set<SObject> is never an instance of Set<Account>
```

Comment: +1. If you're interested, I did some digging around on casting of maps and sets a while back in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-we-cant-upcast-sets

Comment: Makes sense now! Thanks for the answer, and thanks for the links!