# SObject List vs Map instanceof subtype

Tags: apex, force.com, list, map, sobject

```
Map<Id, SObject> sObjectMap = new Map<Id, SObject> ();
System.debug(sObjectMap instanceof Map<Id, Account>); // false
System.debug(sObjectMap.values() instanceof List<Account>); // true

Map<Id, Account> accountMap = (Map<Id,Account>) sObjectMap; // error
List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>) sObjectMap.values(); //success
```

Why can't I treat maps in the same way I do lists? 
Why can I cast `newMap.values()` to `List<Account>` but I can't cast newMap to a `Map<Id,Account>`? 
And how is the `List<SObject>` an instance of subtypes but the same does not apply for `Map<Id, SObject>`?

Comment: It is as it is. The "Why" is only known to the Salesforce Apex language designers. You simply have to live with it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cant accept this as an answer...

Comment: That's your prerogative, but I don't think you'll get a better one. (Note this was actually just a comment, not an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Casting collections is a bit different than casting objects of non-collection types.

Based on the [Collection Casting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting_collections.htm) documentation, what you're trying to do with your map *should likely work*. However, most examples of casting that you'll find are examples of *up*-casting.

The following works just fine

```
Map<Id, Account> acctMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
Map<Id, SObject> sobjMap = (Map<Id, SObject>)acctMap;
```

What you're trying to do here, however, is *down*-casting. Down-casting is a bit of an oddity. It can work, but the requirements are more strict than with up-casting.

The following example will work

```
Map<Id, Account> acctMap1 = new Map<Id, Account>();
acctMap1.put('001000000000000AAA', new Account(Id = '001000000000000AAA'));
Map<Id, SObject> sobjMap = (Map<Id, Account>)acctMap1;
Map<Id, Account> acctMap2 = (Map<Id, Account>)sobjMap;
```

If you start with a map of the correct type, you can up-cast it, and then later down-cast it. Why this works and your example doesn't is something I'm not well-equipped to answer. Like Phil W mentioned, that's something that you'd need to ask the people at Salesforce that maintain the Apex language about.

I did some investigation [on why we can't up-cast Sets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-we-cant-upcast-sets), and managed to come up with a plausible explanation with type-erasure in Java, but I'm not sure if that applies to this situation as well.

### Bonus information

`instanceOf` isn't really reliable when working with collections, see [sfdcfox's answer on this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/apex-string-instanceof-object#125891) for more details.

Keeping track of collection types in your head is one option. Another option is to use the `getSObjectType()` method of the List and Map collection types. It doesn't seem to work with `Map<Id, SObject>` though...