# How can I extend the `Set` class?

Tags: apex, class, inheritance

Is there any way I can extend the `Set` class? I have numerous places in code where if I a set has no items, I want to add all the items in another set, but if it *does* have items, I want to retain only the items in the other set.

This seemed like a good use case for extending the `Set` class, but Apex complains about the lack of `<` following the extending of the set and the declaration of a `Set` argument in the following code:

```
public with sharing class CoreSet extends Set {
    public Boolean retainAllIfPopulated(Set other) {
        return this.size() > 0 ? this.retainAll(other)
                               : this.addAll(other);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to extend the built-in `Set` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible to extend a class if it is not `abstract` or `virtual`. Unlike in `Java` in `Apex` [all classes are `final` by default](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm).
But you can use "composition (over inheritance)" and write something like this:

```
public with sharing class SomeClass {
    private Set<Object> objs;

    public SomeClass(Set<Object> objs) {
        this.objs = objs;
    }

    public Boolean retainAllIfPopulated(Set<Object> other) {
        return objs.size() > 0 ? objs.retainAll(other)
                               : objs.addAll(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to how Sets work in Apex, `Set<Object>` is tough to use. You wouldn't be able to pass a `Set<Account>` into the `SomeClass` constructor or into `retainAllIfPopulated()`. Heck, even `Set<Object> objSet = new Set<Object>(myAccountSet);` doesn't work. This is something [I ran into several years ago](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-we-cant-upcast-sets).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I know that type inference for `Set<?>` is broken in Apex, but I didn't focus on this topic answering this specific question.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible to do this through extending (inheritance) or implementing (interfaces). We'd need generics/templates in the type system, and Apex doesn't provide that.

You *can* make a class that implements the feature you're looking for but, because of the things I mentioned in my first two sentences, you won't be able to automatically substitute your class somewhere that expects a `Set`.

The other gotcha here is that because Sets cannot be up-cast *nor* down-cast (due to a thing called *type erasure*), you'd need to make a separate class for each individual type that you want to provide this feature for.