# What is the simplest way to cast a Map<Object, List<SObject>>?

Tags: apex, conversion, convert

I'm trying to find the most simple way to cast a `map<Object, List<Sobject>>` in any other type like, String, Integer and etc..

Anyone knows how to do this?

This is my code

```
Map<Object, SolicitationItem__c[]> mapHierarchyRequestToItem = (Map<Id,SolicitationItem__c[]>) Collection.of(newRecordsMap.values()).group().byField(SolicitationItem__c.HierarchySolicitation__c).get();
```

ERROR:

> Incompatible types since an instance of Map<Object,List> is never an instance of Map<Id,List<SolicitationItem__c>> (11:72)

Comment: What is `Collection.of()`? Are you using some library? Please [edit] to add details.

Comment: Yes, i'm using this collection => https://github.com/wozniak-michal/apex-collection-library, and i'm trying to know how is the simplest way to convert a Object set in any other type i want....

I'd like to convert my map<Object... in any other type like string, integer

Answer (score 5):

Simplifying things greatly, sets (and the keysets of maps) do not contain enough type information for you to cast between different types. I had a question that went over this in greater detail ([Is there a specific reason why we can't upcast sets?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-we-cant-upcast-sets))

Lists can be cast, and Maps can be cast as long as the key type isn't changing. Sets can never be cast (at time of writing).

If your `mapHierarchyRequestToItem` map contains Ids as the key, you'll need to extract them one by one inside of a loop.

e.g.

```
Set<Id> extractedIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Object data :myMap.keySet()){
    // You can't cast the set, so you need to cast the individual items in the set
    extractedIds.add((Id)data);
}
```

Comment: And yes, it'd probably be a good idea to check to see if something looks like an Id before casting it as an Id. `instanceof` is not really a good check for that though. `Instanceof Id` only checks that the fifth character is 0, which enables hilarity like `system.debug('0' instanceof Id ? 'Looks like an Id to me!' : 'Not an Id');`. Yes, that's a 0 in the fifth position (and smiley emoji, 2-byte characters, filling up the rest), and yes `instanceof` thinks it's an Id.

Comment: Thanks Derek, i'd want to sure what's in my mind, but it is terrible lol

Comment: @DerekF It's a little more capable than "just checks fifth char...", but hilariously less capable than I'd realized. I would have assumed it at least checked `[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}` or something like that.